# как правильно записывать namespace в php?

Tags: php, namespace

Начну с примера после namespace можно ставить `{}` и записывать так:

```
namespace Test 
{
     class Test 
     {
        //...какие то методы
     }
}
```

или так

```
namespace Test;

class Test 
{
    // какие то методы
}
```

так вот, как правильно всегда писать `{}` или `;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

второй вариант правильней.
стандарт: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

из практических соображений, кстати, в первом варианте IDE/редакторы добавят лишнюю табуляцию на весь файл.

Добавлю, что первый вариант удобней использовать, если вы хотите в одном файле описать несколько нэймспейсов. Это может быть нужно, например, для автоматической генерации файлов, цель которых обеспечить автодополнение кода во всем приложении, если приложение использует маппинг класс нэймов, как, например, в фрэймворке Laravel5.*

Comment: ну кстати да, @Razzwan, спасибо за правку, но наверное ее лучше было отдельным ответом, а то я все плюшки получу за ваше дополнение

Comment: для меня не только плюшки являются мотивацией.

Comment: ну хорошо. Ответ в целом лучше получился, спасибо еще раз.